# VS2017 Community genera un error de Aplicación, al Ingeresar nuevos elementos en la Caja de Herramientas

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Reformulando la pregunta: Después de instalado el VS2017 comunnity ver 15.6.1, al dar click derecho sobre la caja de Herramientas > Elejir Elementos, este comienza a cargar los componentes instalados pero llega un momento que El programa deja de funcionar dando un error, Al consultar el Event Log de Windows me aparece lo siguiente:

> Nombre de la aplicación con errores: devenv.exe, versión:
>   15.6.27428.2002, marca de tiempo: 0x5a9f8859 Nombre del módulo con errores: clr.dll, versión: 4.7.2558.0, marca de tiempo: 0x59d413ce
>   Código de excepción: 0xc0000005 Desplazamiento de errores: 0x002e9183
>   Id. del proceso con errores: 0xe9c Hora de inicio de la aplicación con
>   errores: 0x01d3b7cb1ca8b93d Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con
>   errores: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Ruta de acceso del módulo
>   con errores: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Id.
>   del informe: d37566c4-23be-11e8-8353-d027889a64a2

El segundo registro indica lo siguiente:

> Aplicación: devenv.exe Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319 Descripción:
>   el proceso terminó debido a un error interno en el runtime de .NET en
>   la dirección IP 70309183 (70020000) con el código de salida 80131506.

Ya he intentado reparar el Framework 4.0 pero igual sigue indicando error.

Comment: yo tengo la 15.5.7 y no pasa eso.. no sabria que decirte. en realidad la pregunta es casi como irreproducible, sin saber millones de mas cosas..

Comment: Básicamente después de instalar el VS cargo un proyecto nuevo y al darle click en la caja de Herramientas para agrear nuevos elementos este comienza mostrar lista de componentes y dar el error y se cierrar